# Where are the files that control the multisite user dashboard?

Tags: multisite, dashboard

In multisite where are the files that control the dashboard for the multisite user admin? Also where are the files for the normal, standard, wordpress admin dashboard? I want to tweak the mu user dashboard to have some things the normal wordpress admin has. Thanks - Brandon

Answer (score 2):

Most of these files are in `wp/admin/network`. But be aware that some are just wrappers for regular admin files one level up: they include the corresponding file.

What you probably need are the hooks and the function `is_network_admin()` that checks if you are currently on a network admin page.

Most hooks and global variables are the same as in `admin` just with a prefix or suffix `network`. `$pagenow` on the dashboard for example is `dashboard-network`.

The most important difference: there is no network settings API. You can use `wp-admin/admin-post.php` as a workaround ([example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27826/73)).

Comment: is that super admin or is it just the normal user? I fount the super admin I think, but not the normal user.

Comment: Only users with the `'manage_network'` capability can access the network admin area.

Comment: I know, I am saying I need to edit the user admin  not the network admin, but the user admin dashboard, I am going to tweak it to allow customers to add plugins that we control. I just need to know where the dashboard files are for the network user dashboard, nothing else. Thanks for the help, Brandon