# Add site options UI in Multisite Sites > Infos page

Tags: multisite, hooks, options, user-interface

I want to add meta fields for the sites in my network (such as a thumbnail and a category). I know how to do this using [`get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_site_option)/[`add`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/add_site_option)/[`update_site_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/update_site_option), but I'm wondering where I could put the UI to manage those meta fields.

The best place would be in the [Sites > Infos](http://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Sites_Screen#Edit_Site) page, just after the site attributes, but I can't find any hook to hang on. I can add those fields in the "Settings" tab of the same screen, but one has to scroll down a lot to find it, and it gets mixed with advanced settings.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a way to add more lines to the Sites > Infos table : 
[image: My own option in the Sites > Infos table]

It's a little bit ugly, but it works. I simply use the action `admin_footer` to add a bunch of HTML code at the end of the page, and then use jQuery to move it to the right place.

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'user16975_custom_options');
function user16975_custom_options(){
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'site-info.php' == $pagenow ) {
        ?><table><tr id="user16975_custom_options">
            <th scope="row">My own option</th>
            <td><input type="text"/></td>
        </tr></table>
        <script>jQuery(function($){
            $('.form-table tbody').append($('#user16975_custom_options'));
        });</script><?php
    }
}
```

The good part is that as soon as the hook will be available, I can use it without big changes in my code.

Comment: It's simpler with `global $pagenow; if( 'site-info.php' == $pagenow ) {}`. . . . For the records, I just saw that Multilingual Press [creates a new tab in that screen](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/screenshots/).

Comment: Thanks for the `$pagenow` tip @brasofilo, it's cleaner.

Comment: Multilingual Press is using the `manage_sites_custom_column` action to add a column to the **sites table** in `sites.php` page. I want to add a tab in the `site-info.php` page, where you can change the informations linked to **one** of the sites.

Comment: MLP has a tab in `site-info.php`, but I just checked and is injected with jQuery as well :/

Comment: How would you save the data along with the other fields on submit?

Comment: Ya, the data doesn't save at all.

Answer (score 3):

First off all – I agreed, there is no specific hooks in this part of the core that allows to create custom setting fields there. But anyway it is possible.

WordPress has `network_edit_site_nav_links` filter hook which allows to create your custom tab.

But no hooks for the page for the new tab, but it is not a problem anyway because you can achieve the result with simple options page and a little CSS code.

In this tutorial everything is described by steps https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress-multisite/custom-tabs-with-options.html (I think it is no reason to copy all the code from there to this thread).

Comment: This is a great answer, but you should update your answer include the code here. We don't know how long your site will be around.

Comment: Misha's tutorial is excellent, the best example I've found.

Comment:  thank you!

Actually I do not know how long my stackoverflow profile will be around. I received a warning a couple weeks ago. As for my site – it will be around as long as I am alive at least :)

Answer (score 0):

The Site Info admin page's code is here:  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/network/site-info.php

Unfortunately, there don't appear to be any hooks or filters in the `site-info.php` code.

It looks like you'll have to make your own administrative page -- perhaps in the `wp-admin` **Settings** menu -- to handle your `{$verb}_site_option` code.

Comment: I want to have my options UI in the multisite administration zone, (wp-admin/network/...), not in each individual site dashboard. For example, that would be great to have the possibility to add a tab in the Sites > Infos page.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for then -- http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16474/how-to-add-field-for-new-site-wide-option-on-network-settings-screen?rq=1 -- from the **Related** links on the right.

Comment: Nope. The post you are linking is talking about the Settings main menu in the Network admin dashbord (`wp-admin/network/settings`). I'm talking about the page where you can modify individual site options in the Site main menu (`wp-admin/network/site-info.php?id=X`).

Comment: You might be out of luck, then.