# Multisite: How to store global options vs. site options?

Tags: multisite, database, options, network-admin

Hey there I am pretty confused on how to store network wide options within a WordPress multisite installation.

The usual way to store any settings in WordPress is:

```
add_option();
update_option();
delete_option();
```

However the wp_options table is created for each site within a multisite installation.

> The following tables are subsite specific:
>
> ```
> myprefix_siteid_commentmeta          
> myprefix_siteid_comments             
> myprefix_siteid_links                
> myprefix_siteid_options              
> myprefix_siteid_postmeta             
> myprefix_siteid_posts                
> myprefix_siteid_term_relationships   
> myprefix_siteid_term_taxonomy        
> myprefix_siteid_termmeta             
> myprefix_siteid_terms
> ```
>
> The following tables are network wide:
>
> ```
> myprefix_blogs // multisite specific
> myprefix_blog_versions // multisite specific
> myprefix_registration_log // multisite specific
> myprefix_signups // multisite specific
> myprefix_site // multisite specific
> myprefix_sitemeta // multisite specific
> myprefix_users
> myprefix_usermeta
> ```

Do you see the problem? There is no adequate table for storing options for the whole network, which sucks in my opinion.

However I assume that you store network wide options in the base wp_options table (`myprefix_options`). However I cannot use add_option() and update_option() and so on without using `switch_to_blog(1)` before.

Is there a better possibility? If not, how can I get the base wp_options table prefix?

Comment: will let someone else answer, but a nitpick, it is a "network" wide option you want to understand as a multisite may have several networks, global option will be something totally different.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Sure what I mean in my question was network wide options. I know networks of networks are upcoming (and partly implemented), but thats another dimension. Though it would be interesting how to store global options (for many networks), too.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16474/how-to-add-field-for-new-site-wide-option-on-network-settings-screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are functions for saving and retrieving network-wide options:

[`add_network_option();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_network_option/)

[`update_network_option();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_network_option/)

[`get_network_option();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_network_option/)

The values of these options are stored in `wp_sitemeta`.

Comment: Ah this is the correct location. The site id is zero and therefore the option is for the whole network, thanks.

Comment: For site (=network of blogs) options get_site_option() is used.

Comment: `get_site_option()` is just a wrapper for `get_network_option()`. `*_network_option` is the terminology since 4.4.